# sharepoint javascript on click shape

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, onclick, shapes, visio

I need to add an onclick event to shapes from Visio in SharePoint, with JavaScript, like the  vwaControl handler shapeselectionchanged but on click, is there any way I could do that?

I'm sorry about my English is not my native language.

I hope you can understand me.

Comment: the shapes are irregular, and a lot so I guess mapping the image is out of the question, if that could be done. but if it's the only way could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar.
You can use the shapeSelectionChangedHandler to handle clicks to. As far as I know there is no onClick functionality, but shapeSelectionChangedHandler works fine for me.

See:
[Programming with Visio in SharePoint, create new Outlook meeting in ?Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633916/programming-with-visio-in-sharepoint-need-to-add-the-logic-in-javascript)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg243427.aspx for guide to set it up with Content WebPart and so on.

Code I use, just add what you want in `shapeSelectionChangedHandler = function(source, args) {}`

```
<script language="javascript">
var app = Sys.Application;

app.add_load(onApplicationLoad);

// hold an instance of the Visio VWA control
var vwaControl; 

var shapeSelectionChangedHandler = null;


function onApplicationLoad()
{
    vwaControl= new Vwa.VwaControl("WebPartWPQ4");
    vwaControl.addHandler("diagramcomplete", onDiagramComplete);
    vwaControl.addHandler("shapeselectionchanged", shapeSelectionChangedHandler);
}

function onDiagramComplete()
{
    var vwaPage = vwaControl.getActivePage(); 
    vwaPage.setZoom(35); // force the initial zoom level
}


shapeSelectionChangedHandler = function(source, args)
{
    // get the selected shape from the shapes on the page
    var vwaPage = vwaControl.getActivePage(); 
    var vwaShapes = vwaPage.getShapes(); 
    var shape = vwaShapes.getItemById(args);

    // get the data to display for the selected shape
    var data = shape.getShapeData();

    var strRoomName = ""; 
    var strFloorNumber = "";
    var strCapacity = ""; 
    var strStatus = ""; 

    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
    {
        if (data[j].label == "RoomName")
        {
            strRoomName = data[j].value;
            continue;
        } 

        if (data[j].label == "FloorNumber")
        {
            strFloorNumber = data[j].value;
            continue;
        }

        if (data[j].label == "Capacity")
        {
            strCapacity = data[j].value;
            continue;
        }        

        if (data[j].label == "RoomStatus")
        {
            strStatus = data[j].value;
            continue;
        }                
    }

    // get the selected state input and set its value
    var  inputRoomName = document.getElementById('strRoomName');
    inputRoomName.value = strRoomName;

    var inputFloorNumber = document.getElementById('strFloorNumber');
    inputFloorNumber.value = strFloorNumber;

    var inputCapacity = document.getElementById('strCapacity');
    inputCapacity.value = strCapacity;    

    var inputStatus = document.getElementById('strStatus');
    inputStatus.value = strStatus;        
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to be on click, because i need to update a list, every time they click, so far i could do it with double click, adding the shapeClicked function to the document.onclick (only in the visio web access page), and getting the vwaShapes.getselectedShape, to know which shape is selected, and needs to be changed in the list. Anyway, do you know how to link a new list to the shapes via javascript, i can create retrieve or update, but i dont know how to connect it with visio web access